# NullPointerException - Java - Webservice Client on top of WCF (using WS-Security)

Tags: java, web-services, ws-security

I'm building a WCF Service using wsHttpBinding.
(with WS-Security and Message Level Security)

Now I'd like to build a JAVA client for it, using..

- Metro
- Netbeans

Everything worked fine so far.. I've created the Java Client from the WSDL.

Now whenever I call the client proxy I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.security.impl.policyconv.BindingProcessor.requireSC(BindingProcessor.java:330)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.security.impl.policyconv.BindingProcessor.addPrimaryTargets(BindingProcessor.java:310)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.security.impl.policyconv.SymmetricBindingProcessor.process(SymmetricBindingProcessor.java:154)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.security.impl.policyconv.XWSSPolicyGenerator.process(XWSSPolicyGenerator.java:200)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.security.impl.policyconv.XWSSPolicyGenerator.process(XWSSPolicyGenerator.java:157)
         at
 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.constructPolicyHolder(SecurityTubeBase.java:1233)
         at
 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.addIncomingProtocolPolicy(SecurityClientTube.java:683)
         at
 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.buildProtocolPolicy(SecurityTubeBase.java:1206)
         at
 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.collectPolicies(SecurityTubeBase.java:735)
         at
 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityTubeBase.<init>(SecurityTubeBase.java:288)
         at
 com.sun.xml.wss.jaxws.impl.SecurityClientTube.<init>(SecurityClientTube.java:144)
         at
 com.sun.xml.wss.provider.wsit.SecurityTubeFactory.createTube(SecurityTubeFactory.java:227)
         at 
 com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubeCreator.createTube(TubeCreator.java:77)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.assembler.TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl$MetroTubelineAssembler.createClient(TubelineAssemblerFactoryImpl.java:121)
         at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.createPipeline(Stub.java:224)
         at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:201)
         at com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.<init>(Stub.java:174)
         at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.<init>(SEIStub.java:81)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createEndpointIFBaseProxy(WSServiceDelegate.java:602)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:344)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:326)
         at
 com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:308)
         at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:134)
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging through to see what is actually null?

Comment: Honestly.. I'm a .NET expert, but a Java noop..

Comment: Can you debug into the Java / Metro Sources?
And if - how in Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Metro 2.0 to Metro 2.3 helps a lot, at least you'll see a meaningful exception, in my case it was that the encryption algorithm wasn't available in my JRE installation, I had to install the Bouncy Castle encryption libraries (http://bit.ly/8JWAF).

**Edit:** Here is an article about comunicating a jax-ws client with a WCF service, hope it helps: [Comunicating Jax-ws client with WCF service with server sertificate](https://github.com/JeyDotC/articles/blob/master/Comunicating%20Jax-ws%20client%20with%20WCF%20service%20with%20server%20sertificate.md)

Answer (score -1):

Set a breakpoint in `BindingProcessor.java` at line `330`. You 'step over' with F6, as I recall.

If you're a .NET expert, then that means you have some basic programming knowlegde. Every programmer should know how to debug a program.

Read more on NetBeans debugging [here](http://www.cs.uga.edu/~shoulami/sp2009/cs1301/tutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial/NetBeansDebuggerTutorial.htm), and debug your code to see where the argument for the `requireSC` method isn't being initialized.

Comment: Only trouble is.. there's no BindingProcessor.java file anywhere where I would look for it..

Comment: So then you cannot find out what parameter is being passed to requireSC? This seems like a very on-the-surface bug. Should be sometihing obvious, in my opinion.

Comment: Netbeans usually doesn't go into jar files when debugging so it is worthless. An alternative would be to debug using Metro source code. Or if there is a way to tell netbeans to debug jar files I'd appreciate.

Comment: @user1778770 Yeah, here's a way: use Eclipse.